# How to have text dynamically change with React, but not call the change in Render?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs

I'm trying to build a very simple app with `React` that will tell you how many days have past since a given date. I am using `React`, `Moments`, and `ReactJS Datepicker` as the foundation of this app for quick implementation.

I'm getting an `error` when I attempt to pick a date saying

```
warning.js:44 
Warning: setState(...): Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within 'render' or another component's constructor)
```

I understand it means I can't have a function update a `state` I am currently displaying due to `render` issues, but am having a hard time figuring out how I can get such functionality without updating it in the `render` method.

This is the current app:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import DatePicker from 'react-datepicker';
import moment from 'moment';
import './App.css';
import 'react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css';

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
    this.state = {
      startDate: moment(),
      dateDiff: moment(),
      dateCheck: false
    };
  }
  handleChange(date) {
    this.setState({
      startDate: date,
      dateCheck: true
    });
  }
  showDiff(date, dateCheck) {
    if (dateCheck) {
      this.setState({
        dateCheck: false,
        dateDiff: moment().startOf(date).fromNow()
      });
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="DatePicker">
          <DatePicker
            selected={this.state.startDate}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            showYearDropdown
            dateFormatCalendar="MMMM"
            isClearable={true}
            placeholderText='Enter A Date' />

        </div>
        <div>
          {this.showDiff(this.state.startDate, this.state.dateCheck)}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

I'm trying to have it update the number of calculated days every time a new date is selected, and thought the  `dateCheck` flag would help, but it didn't.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React automatically re-renders parts of the DOM that need updating upon state change. The idea is to tell React **what** you want it to render, not **how** you want it to render.

So in your case, if you just want React to render the date difference from now, you need only change `startDate` when it updates. Here's some code to try to illustrate what I'm suggesting:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import DatePicker from 'react-datepicker';
import moment from 'moment';
import './App.css';
import 'react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css';

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
    this.state = {
      startDate: moment()
    };
  }
  handleChange(date) {
    this.setState({
      startDate: date
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="DatePicker">
          <DatePicker
            selected={this.state.startDate}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            showYearDropdown
            dateFormatCalendar="MMMM"
            isClearable={true}
            placeholderText='Enter A Date' />
        </div>
        <div>
          {this.state.startDate.fromNow()}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Awesome! I'm so stupid for not realizing that :( 

I'll mark your post as the answer, but for people trying to do this as well, I made another mistake and initialized dateDiff as a moment object and the `fromNow` function returns a string which generated an error.

Simply making `dateDiff: ''` fixed the issue. 

The text shows correctly now, but it doesn't actually update and just keeps saying a few seconds from now regardless of the date I select :(

Edit* I had to add another line to allow datePicker to know what date to display `startDate: date` in the same `setState` call.

Comment: Ah I see what the code was trying to do now. I originally just answered for concept instead of thinking about the logic behind it. I've modified it now - give it a try and let me know if that works :)

Comment: That's fantastic! Yeah, I see how you did that now. Thank you so much :)

Edit* Now I feel ridiculous! My original idea was that I could tell how many days it has been between now and a given date, but after I entered my birthday it just gave it to me in years... back to the drawing board!

Comment: For anyone interested: I added a new initial state `today: moment().startOf('day')` and instead of `this.state.startDate.fromNow()` I did `this.state.startDate.diff(this.state.today, 'days')`

Hope this helps!

Comment: Karin has already answered the question. But as a rule - do not trigger state change from render